# How do I rename xlabels for this histogram?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm making a histogram for a database about Family Income and Educaction level, all fine but when I'm trying to rename x labels I simply can't:

```
cces$faminc_new1 = recode(cces$faminc_new,
                         "1" = "Less than $10,000",
                         "2" = "$10000 - $19,999",
                         "3" = "$20000 - $29,999",
                         "4" = "$30000 - $39,999",
                         "5" = "$40000 - $49,999",
                         "6" = "$50000 - $59,999",
                         "7" = "$60000 - $69,999",
                         "8" = "$70000 - $79,999",
                         "9" = "$80000 - $99,999",
                         "10"= "$100000 - $119,999",
                         "11"= "$120000 - $149,999",
                         "12"= "$150000 - $199,999",
                         "13"= "$200000 - $249,999",
                         "14"= "$250000 - $349,999",
                         "15"= "$350000 - $499,999",
                         "16"= "$500000 or more")

cces$educ1 = recode(cces$educ,
                   "1" = "1 No HS",
                   "2" = "2 HS graduate",
                   "3" = "3 Some college",
                   "4" = "4 2-year",
                   "5" = "5 4-year",
                   "6" = "6 Post-grad")
```

This scatter plot is perfect:
[image]

But I can't rename x labels for this hist:

```
cces %>% ggplot(aes(x= faminc_new, colour = educ1, fill = educ1)) +
  geom_histogram() + scale_x_discrete(labels = c("1" = "Less than $10,000",
                         "2" = "20k",
                         "3" = "30k",
                         "4" = "40k",
                         "5" = "50",
                         "6" = "60",
                         "7" = "70k",
                         "8" = "80k",
                         "9" = "100k",
                         "10"= "120k",
                         "11"= "150k",
                         "12"= "200k",
                         "13"= "250k",
                         "14"= "350k",
                         "15"= "500k",
                         "16"= ">500k"))
```

[image]

faminc_new and educ are continous and faminc_new1 and educ1 are discrete.

How I can put the labels from faminc_new1 to the x labels of my histogram?

Comment: my guess is it is not a discrete scale, so change ` scale_x_discrete` to ` scale_x_continuous` and it will work. And please give a reproducible example, see [mcve]

Comment: @denis That didn't work

Comment: sorry i did not work. I cannot do much more without an example that reproduce your problem

Comment: R doesn't give me any error, just plots the histogram as you can see

Comment: try `geom_bar`, I feel you aren't looking for a histogram.

Comment: @Suren I've already tried that

Comment: Have you tried new code now included in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the expected outcome is a bar plot. So one option is to use `geom_bar`.

With histogram, there will be automatic breaks. So manual new labels would not work. If you want to insist using `geom_histogram`, you will have to specify breaks.

Following works after introducing breaks.

```
mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x= cyl, y= gear, colour = gear)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = c("40k", "60k", "80k"), breaks = c(4, 6, 8))


mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = cyl, y = gear, colour = gear, fill = gear)) + 
  geom_histogram(stat = "identity") +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = c("40k", "60k", "80k"), breaks = c(4, 6, 8))
```

Comment: I know that you are right, with geom_bar breaks are automatic but for this problem, it didn't function :(

Comment: It is best to include a working example so we can better understand the problem.

Comment: thank you, a bar plot plus scale_x_continuous was the answer!